# Найти одинаковые объекты в массиве

Tags: алгоритм

Есть массив вот такого формата

```js
const listTest = [
    {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Чизкейк', id: 'd3gh56dfg23jkl8qw', price: 4.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Клубничный пирог', id: 'd4bnm2345dfg67kj1', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Фруктовый салат', id: 'd5dfg23kl56dfg78nm2', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1}, 
    {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1}
]
```

Нужно те значения, которые повторяются, удалить и оставить только одно и в нём изменить значение `count` должно быть равно сумме всех повторяющихся массивов.
Т.е должно получится:

```js
const newList = [         
    {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 3},
    {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 3},
    {name: 'Чизкейк', id: 'd3gh56dfg23jkl8qw', price: 4.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Клубничный пирог', id: 'd4bnm2345dfg67kj1', price: 3.99, count: 1},
    {name: 'Фруктовый салат', id: 'd5dfg23kl56dfg78nm2', price: 3.99, count: 1},
]
```

Comment: сгруппируйте по идентификатору да суммируйте

Answer (score 1):

Код представил на JS:

```js
 const listTest = [
      {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Чизкейк', id: 'd3gh56dfg23jkl8qw', price: 4.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Тирамису', id: 'd2dfg234njkl78mn', price: 3.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Клубничный пирог', id: 'd4bnm2345dfg67kj1', price: 3.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Фруктовый салат', id: 'd5dfg23kl56dfg78nm2', price: 3.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1},
      {name: 'Шоколадный торт', id: 'd1jkl2345dfg67mn', price: 4.99, count: 1}
    ];
    
    const groupedItems = listTest.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const existingItem = acc.find(i => i.id === item.id);
      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.count += item.count;
      } else {
        acc.push(item);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(groupedItems);
```